# Show row in a second sheet based on a cell being filled in a first sheet but conditionaly to a drop-down list choice selected in the same column (vba)

Tags: excel, vba, row

I have this code (it works) that show or hide rows in a sheet if a cell has a value that is not anything (someone wrote something in it) in another sheet. Ex. If I wrote something in B11, in the second sheet, it will show row 9 :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.address = "B11" Then
        If Target.Value <> "" Then
            Sheets("Sheet2").Rows("9").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else
            Sheets("Sheet2").Rows("9").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm looking for a way to adapt this code so that it only works if on the same row, but a different column in the first sheet, there's also a specific option that is selected in a drop-down list, like "success". Does somebody know how ?

Comment: `Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(Target.Row).EntireRow` ?  It's not really clear what you want to do.

Comment: Right now, with this code I can show a row in a sheet based on the fact that I entered something in a cell in a first sheet. However, I would like to be able to show the row in the second sheet, as mentioned, but only if in another cell on the same row, i choose a specific option in a drop-down list.

Comment: "another cell on the same row" in which sheet though?  Sheet2?

Comment: In the first sheet. So my target is not only B11 but also something like G11 in the first sheet but this cell is a drop-down list.

Comment: Edited my answer below - try that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure I understand what you need to do but something like this should work:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'either of these two cells was changed?
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B11,G11")) Is Nothing Then
    
        'hide/unhide row on second sheet
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").rows(9).Hidden = _
          Len(Me.Range("B11").Value) = 0 Or Me.Range("G11").Value <> "success"
        
    End If
End Sub
```